# Children's scifi picture book with a spaceman visiting a large green spaceship

Tags: story-identification, books

My grandma had a stash of books for the grand kids and one used to constantly play on my mind. This was 30 years ago.

There was a guy in a little spaceship (possibly lost) .. Suddenly he is going past this massive green spaceship that is about 1000 times bigger than his. It looks ancient and relic-y. It's completely dead silent. It kinda made you feel a bit spooked. He goes onto it to investigate it. I can't recall what happened next, but I think maybe they killed themselves off.

It is a picture book but may have some words and it is very 60's/70's style.

To make it worse it may have even been a mini story in a kinda bunch of short drawn stories.

Comment: Welcome to Science Fiction & Fantasy! This question would be improved by going through the checklists here; [How to ask a good story-ID question?](https://scifi.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/9335/how-to-ask-a-good-story-id-question)